# droppable not registering drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I'm trying to make the list item that I'm dragging disappear (by adding a class) when it's dropped.

I have the console log for when it's grabbed, and it's dropping fine but no addClass or log message is happening when I drop it. Any help much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('.draggable-demo-product').mousedown(function(){
                    $(this).addClass('grabbed');
                    console.log('grabbed');
            }); 
            $('.droppable').droppable({
                drop: function(){
                $('.draggable-demo-product').addClass('dropped');
                    console.log('dropped');
                }
            });        
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making use of your code I have setup a jsFiddle and everything works fine. Check whether you have included all the required js libraries in your HTML file.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrpruthvi/4d7GF/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
        $('.drag').mousedown(function(){
                $(this).addClass('grabbed');
                console.log('grabbed');
        }).draggable(); 
        $('.drop').droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui){
            $('.drag').addClass('dropped');
                console.log('dropped');
            }
        });        
});
```